# How can i check if there is in an item in one list that isn't in the other list?

Tags: c#, list

```
List<string> equipment = new List<string>();
equipment.Add("Football");
equipment.Add("Golf Ball");
equipment.Add("Baseball");

List<string> myEquipment = new List<string>();
myEquipment.Add("Football");
myEquipment.Add("Golf Ball");
myEquipment.Add("Basketball");
```

If i have the above, how would i check if there is an item in myEquipment that isn't in equipment?

Comment: How long are the lists? If you solve this problem naively, as some of the answers posted so far do, you can end up making the operation extremely expensive.

Comment: Are you committed to the data structure being a list? You can get better performance if you use a hash set instead.

Comment: what could i do if it was a hash set?

Comment: Do you care about whether there *exists* any such item, or do you need *the sequence of such items*?  If you've got a jar of coins and you want to know if there exists a 2010 quarter, you can stop after you find the first quarter. If you want all the 2010 quarters, you cannot stop until you've checked every coin.

Comment: Membership checking is cheaper on a hash set, and hash sets provide efficient operations such as ExceptWith. If the purpose of your question is to perform set subtraction, don't implement it yourself; put the items hash sets and then use the provided efficient set subtraction method. Hash sets also support efficient union and intersection operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to do this pretty easily

```
myEquipment.Any(c => !equipment.Contains(c));
```

If you need the items you could do

```
var notInEquipment = myEquipment.Where(c => !equipment.Contains(c));
```

Comment: Note that this technique is n-squared in the size of the lists; this is really bad if the lists are long.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var diff = myEquipment.Except(equipment);
```

Another solution is to use [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) and `ExceptWith`. It has almost the same complexity with previous solution (both `O(n)`), but `HashSet` will skip the duplicated values

```cs
var set = new HashSet<string>(equipment);
var mySet = new HashSet<string>(myEquipment);

mySet.ExceptWith(set);
```

`Contains` method also work, but has some performance overhead

```cs
var item = equipment.FirstOrDefault(e => !myEquipment.Contains(e));
```

You'll get the first item, which isn't present in a second list, or `null` value

Comment: Note that this technique is n-squared in the size of the lists; this is really bad if the lists are long.

Comment: this isn't exactly what i needed, but it's still extremely helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linq `Except` method:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> equipment = new List<string>();
    equipment.Add("Football");
    equipment.Add("Golf Ball");
    equipment.Add("Baseball");

    List<string> myEquipment = new List<string>();
    myEquipment.Add("Football");
    myEquipment.Add("Golf Ball");
    myEquipment.Add("Basketball");

    var missingEquipment = myEquipment.Except(equipment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two way look up to get items that don't exist in other from both lists:

```
    var b = equipment.Concat(myEquipment).ToLookup(x => x)
            .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count()})\
            .Where(x => x.Count == 1);
```